# The new list item should fade in

Tags: css, angular, list, fade

I have a list in my TS file that is rendered dynamically to the template:

```
    <ul*ngFor ="let product of products let ind = index" >
        <li>
            <span> Text will be rendered here</span>                
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I need the item that is being pushed to `MyList` animates.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly. The class is already in my CSS file. But I want this to be assigned to the new item only.

Comment: you should use angular 5 animations

Comment: My first issue is where and how in the template I should add the class.

Comment: shouldn't it be [ngClass]="{'fade': fadeFlag}"   ?

Comment: Where exactly? Inside ul or li? I tried both and it did not work. I need a suggested solution to see where I have made mistake.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example of how to do it with the animation framework

The **animation** (transform it if you needed):

```
import {
  trigger,
  style,
  transition,
  animate,
} from '@angular/animations';

export const FadeAnimation = trigger(
  'fadeAnimation', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({
          opacity: 0
        }
      ),
      animate(
        200,
        style({
          opacity: 1
        })
      )
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate(
        200,
        style({
          opacity: 0
        })
      )
    ])
  ]
);
```

In the **component** (import the animation):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-selector',
  templateUrl: './your-component-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component-name.component.css'],
  animations: [
    FadeAnimation,
  ]
})
```

In the **html** (if the condition is true: opacity is set to 1, else opacity is set to 0):

```
<ul*ngFor ="let product of products let i = index" >
    <li [ngClass]="{'highlightClass': i%2==0}" [@fadeAnimation]="true">
        <span> Text will be rendered here</span>
        <span> More text here </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the animation code must to be in other file

Comment: you need to adjust the condition at your needs